# Can't get date conditions to work in MYSQLI query

Tags: php

I'm trying to get users tracked birthdays to show up one week before and one week after the tracked person's birthday. But it doesn't seem to work. The MySQL table for user_birthdays consists of these 4 rows: bid, bname, bdate, buser_id. The bdate is saved with the format YYYY-MM-DD in the database.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_birthdays WHERE bdate BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%m-%d') - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%m-%d') + INTERVAL 7 DAY AND buser_id='{$_SESSION['id']}'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
```

Everything works when I'm not using the date conditions.

Comment: What errore do you get?

Comment: Why the , '%m-%d', your not printing anything or is the bdate in different format? Iis it a date field?

Comment: @Grumpy Correct, it was not necessary to use %m-%d... I'm a beginner. Learning by failing.

Comment: Please do not add `SOLVED` to the title of your question. Either post your own answer below (as an actual answer, not a comment), or upvote/accept the provided answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that bdate is correctly formatted, try this one:

`WHERE bdate BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY), '%m-%d') AND DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY), '%m-%d')`

otherwise you could calculate the min and max dates from php and insert them in `between $min_date and $max_date`

Comment: I just solved it by using $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_birthdays WHERE date(concat_ws('-', year(now()), month(bdate), day(bdate))) BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 WEEK AND buser_id='{$_SESSION['id']}'"; Thank you for the answer though!